# OpenGL applying glMaterial to only one object

Tags: opengl

With the code below I am trying to apply lighting to the sun. When I apply GL_EMISSION it seems to apply the lighting to the other objects that are created too.

```
GL11.glPushMatrix();
        {


            // how shiny are the front faces of the sun (specular exponent)
            float sunFrontShininess  = 2.0f;
            // specular reflection of the front faces of the sun
            float sunFrontSpecular[] = {0.1f, 0.1f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
            // diffuse reflection of the front faces of the sun
            float sunFrontDiffuse[]  = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};


            float sunEmission[] = {0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1f};

            // set the material properties for the sun using OpenGL

            //???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
            GL11.glMaterial(GL11.GL_FRONT, GL11.GL_EMISSION, FloatBuffer.wrap(sunEmission));
            //???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????



            GL11.glMaterialf(GL11.GL_FRONT, GL11.GL_SHININESS, sunFrontShininess);
            GL11.glMaterial(GL11.GL_FRONT, GL11.GL_SPECULAR, FloatBuffer.wrap(sunFrontSpecular));
            GL11.glMaterial(GL11.GL_FRONT, GL11.GL_DIFFUSE, FloatBuffer.wrap(sunFrontDiffuse));

            // position and draw the sun using a sphere quadric object
            GL11.glTranslatef(4.0f, 7.0f, -19.0f);
            new Sphere().draw(0.5f,10,10);



        }
        GL11.glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: OpenGL is a state machine. If you change a state it is kept stated, until you change it again, even beyond frames.

Comment: General comment: If you are just starting to learn OpenGL, use a more recent tutorial. `glMaterial`, `glPushMatrix`, `glTranslate` and so on have been deprecated for over 10 years. If you learn OpenGL, learn the current version with shaders.

Comment: @NicoSchertler my university lecturer is teaching us this way, therefore thats the way we have to do it

Comment: Then this is a perfectly fine reason. Just wanted to mention it in case you just picked a random OpenGL tutorial.

Comment: Just set the emissive material to black after you have rendered the sun. Edit Rabbid76 already pointed it out